# Typescript Typings and NPM

Tags: typescript, npm, definitelytyped

I'm excited that NPM now has built-in support for importing TypeScript type wrappers.  However, I'm finding inconsistency in how these are maintained.  For example, I tried to import "node-git" and "@types/node-git" and, while both worked, they seemed to be very different APIs and didn't play well together.

What is the best practice in this scenario?  Should I import the type wrapper for a library first, check its version, and then import that version of the library specifically?  Do I need to get up to speed on creating TypeScript wrappers of my own (and can they be tool-generated)?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: a javascript library and a typescript wrapper could be two different projects from different people, most js libraries have this situation because not all js developers use typescript

Comment: as for "tool-generated" if library is documented well with JSDocs then maybe this one could do : https://github.com/englercj/tsd-jsdoc

Comment: These were helpful comments.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's no defined "best practice". Imo you should use whatever version of the library (i.e. `node-git`) that you want. If there is a types package corresponding to that version, then great. If not, consider creating a PR in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped) (assuming that the types package is maintained by DefinitelyTyped). If you can't wait for your PR to be merged, you can add your updated `index.d.ts` file to your project, and use the `typeRoots` compiler option to tell typescript where the file is.

For example, if you add your updated types to `src/types/node_git/index.d.ts`, then add this to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["src/types", "node_modules/@types"]
    }
}
```